# Sending HTML in an e-mail message's body

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send an e-mail containing HTML, but the HTML shows up literally. How can I send an HTML link? Here's my current code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]
{"[EMAIL PROTECTED]"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
"Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
"<html><body>Example</body></html>");
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send
mail..."));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + link_val + "\">" + text_value+ "</a>"));
```

Comment: i used this code... when i send mail from email of android got plain text at the place of text_value...

Comment: yes it's working but from gmail account, when i am sending any data from my gmail account then i can access html links. but when i am sending same html data through email option of intent chooser then only getting plain text instead of html link.

Comment: well i got the solution:......
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html
    .fromHtml(body));

Comment: @Droid: What is body ? I mean i want to send the html that is in android assets folder and also want to show the content of that html file in Mail during sending the mail then how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be bugs in both gmail and email apps on Android. The email app cannot send links correctly if you put it into html, gmail sends the link okay. Gmail doesn't display the email with the links though, and the email app does display them correctly so they are clickable. At least it is the case if you are using custom uri's.

Answer (score 0):

API 16++ has `android.content.Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT` on APIs before 16. You should add this as an extra to the intent you normally use.
Also when specifying HTML text you need to add regular alternative text as well

So your code would look like

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]
{"[EMAIL PROTECTED]"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
"Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT,
"<html><body>Example</body></html>");
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send
mail..."));
```